# Primefaces Auto Image Upload - Progress Bar Stuck After Upload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

[image]

I am using FileUpload Auto in the Primefaces Showcase http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/file/upload/auto.xhtml?jfwid=f92d9

Upload is successful but progess bar stucks in the screen like that. Is anyone faced this problem before?

```html
<p:fileUpload listener="#{productBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"
              update="messages" auto="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/>
```

I used this code in the JSF

Comment: Please add code.  That progressbar is coming from somewhere not from the FileUpload.

Comment: And check for errors in the browser console.